# Way to keep header footer distance same for first page, smaller after that?

Tags: margins

Is there a way in which i can keep the original header/footer size for the first page, then use smaller margins from the second page then on in?

Comment: Do you start the second page by explicit page break (`\newpage` or `\clearpage`) or it comes *naturally*?

Comment: Does the text flow naturally from the first to the second, or does is there an abrupt break? The latter is far easier to manage than the former.

Comment: for the second page i use `\newpage` and then the ones following this i use a mixture @Masroor and @Werner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet will be to use the `\newgeometry` command from the
`geometry` package.

`\newgeometry` allows
you to change page dimensions in the middle of the document.

For details, please see Section 7
Changing layout mid-document of the [package documentation.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf)

Here is the code with the above idea.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=30.0mm,right=30.0mm,top=30.0mm,bottom=30.0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

% First page with wider margins

\lipsum[1-7]

\clearpage

% Later pages with narrower margins

\newgeometry{left=10.0mm,right=10.0mm,top=10.0mm,bottom=10.0mm}

\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, but what is the `\lipsum[1-7]` for? @Masroor

Comment: It is only for generating dummy text. Don't worry, your actual text will work flawlessly.